Abstracting away ANSI escape sequences
I have an application that requires ANSI escape sequences, so I have attempted to abstract away the magic strings out of the code (they were previously macros) into a separate translation layer, behind a very simple API:
#ifndef SEQUENCES_H
#define SEQUENCES_H 1

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

enum esc_seq_id : uint8_t {
    CLR_WIN,
    CLR_WIN_UPTO_CUR,
    CLR_WIN_UPTO_END,
    POS_CUR_TOP_LEFT,
    CLR_LINE_UPTO_END,
    POS_CUR_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
    GET_CUR_POS,
    HIDE_CUR,
    SHOW_CUR,
    COLOR_INVERT,
    COLOR_NORMAL,
    RESET_ALL_ATTRIB,
    COLOR_BLACK_FORE,
    COLOR_RED_FORE,
    COLOR_GREEN_FORE,
    COLOR_YELLOW_FORE,
    COLOR_BLUE_FORE,
    COLOR_MAGENTA_FORE,
    COLOR_CYAN_FORE,
    COLOR_WHITE_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_BLACK_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_RED_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_GREEN_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_YELLOW_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_BLUE_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_MAGENTA_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_CYAN_FORE,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE_FORE,
    COLOR_BLACK_BACK,
    COLOR_RED_BACK,
    COLOR_GREEN_BACK,
    COLOR_YELLOW_BACK,
    COLOR_BLUE_BACK,
    COLOR_MAGENTA_BACK,
    COLOR_CYAN_BACK,
    COLOR_DEFAULT_FORE,
    COLOR_DEFAULT_BACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_BACK_BLACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_RED_BACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_GREEN_BACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_YELLOW_BACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_BLUE_BACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_MAGENTA_BACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_CYAN_BACK,
    COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE_BACK,
    ESC_SEQ_COUNT               /* This should always be the last element. */
};

[[gnu::pure]] const char *get_seq_name(uint8_t id);
[[gnu::pure]] size_t get_seq_len(uint8_t id);

#endif                          /* SEQUENCES_H */

and the corresponding source file:
#include "new.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SLEN(s) (sizeof(s) - 1)

#define DEF(name)   \
        { .seq = name, .len = SLEN(name) }

static const struct {
    const char *const seq;
    const size_t len;
} esc_seq[] = {
    [CLR_WIN]                   = DEF("\x1b[2J"),
    [CLR_WIN_UPTO_CUR]          = DEF("\x1b[1J"),
    [CLR_WIN_UPTO_END]          = DEF("\x1b[0J"),
    [POS_CUR_TOP_LEFT]          = DEF("\x1b[H"),
    [CLR_LINE_UPTO_END]         = DEF("\x1b[K"),
    [POS_CUR_BOTTOM_RIGHT]      = DEF("\x1b[999C\x1b[999B"),
    [GET_CUR_POS]               = DEF("\x1b[6n"),
    [HIDE_CUR]                  = DEF("\x1b[?25l"),
    [SHOW_CUR]                  = DEF("\x1b[?25h"),
    [COLOR_INVERT]              = DEF("\x1b[7m"),
    [COLOR_NORMAL]              = DEF("\x1b[m"),
    [RESET_ALL_ATTRIB]          = DEF("\x1b[0m"),
    [COLOR_BLACK_FORE]          = DEF("\x1b[30m"),
    [COLOR_RED_FORE]            = DEF("\x1b[31m"),
    [COLOR_GREEN_FORE]          = DEF("\x1b[32m"),
    [COLOR_YELLOW_FORE]         = DEF("\x1b[33m"),
    [COLOR_BLUE_FORE]           = DEF("\x1b[34m"),
    [COLOR_MAGENTA_FORE]        = DEF("\x1b[35m"),
    [COLOR_CYAN_FORE]           = DEF("\x1b[36m"),
    [COLOR_WHITE_FORE]          = DEF("\x1b[37m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_BLACK_FORE]   = DEF("\x1b[90m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_RED_FORE]     = DEF("\x1b[91m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_GREEN_FORE]   = DEF("\x1b[92m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_YELLOW_FORE]  = DEF("\x1b[93m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_BLUE_FORE]    = DEF("\x1b[94m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_MAGENTA_FORE] = DEF("\x1b[95m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_CYAN_FORE]    = DEF("\x1b[96m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE_FORE]   = DEF("\x1b[97m"),
    [COLOR_BLACK_BACK]          = DEF("\x1b[40m"),
    [COLOR_RED_BACK]            = DEF("\x1b[41m"),
    [COLOR_GREEN_BACK]          = DEF("\x1b[42m"),
    [COLOR_YELLOW_BACK]         = DEF("\x1b[43m"),
    [COLOR_BLUE_BACK]           = DEF("\x1b[44m"),
    [COLOR_MAGENTA_BACK]        = DEF("\x1b[45m"),
    [COLOR_CYAN_BACK]           = DEF("\x1b[46m"),
    [COLOR_DEFAULT_FORE]        = DEF("\x1b[39m"),
    [COLOR_DEFAULT_BACK]        = DEF("\x1b[49m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_BACK_BLACK]   = DEF("\x1b[100m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_RED_BACK]     = DEF("\x1b[101m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_GREEN_BACK]   = DEF("\x1b[102m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_YELLOW_BACK]  = DEF("\x1b[103m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_BLUE_BACK]    = DEF("\x1b[104m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_MAGENTA_BACK] = DEF("\x1b[105m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_CYAN_BACK]    = DEF("\x1b[106m"),
    [COLOR_BRIGHT_WHITE_BACK]   = DEF("\x1b[107m"),
};

static_assert(sizeof esc_seq / sizeof esc_seq[0] == ESC_SEQ_COUNT,
    "Mismatch between esc_seq array and enum esc_seq_id!");

[[gnu::pure]] const char *get_seq_name(uint8_t id)
{
    /* This assertion would get disabled in release build if NDEBUG is defined. */
    assert(id < ESC_SEQ_COUNT);    
    return esc_seq[id].seq;
}

[[gnu::pure]] size_t get_seq_len(uint8_t id)
{
    /* This assertion would get disabled in release build if NDEBUG is defined. */
    assert(id < ESC_SEQ_COUNT);    
    return esc_seq[id].len;
}

to be used like this:
#include <unistd.h>

#include "new.h"

int main(void)
{
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, get_seq_name(CLR_WIN), get_seq_len(CLR_WIN));
    sleep(1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, get_seq_name(POS_CUR_TOP_LEFT), get_seq_len(POS_CUR_TOP_LEFT));
    sleep(1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, get_seq_name(COLOR_RED_FORE), get_seq_len(COLOR_RED_FORE));
    sleep(1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hello, World!", sizeof "Hello, World!" - 1);
    sleep(1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, get_seq_name(CLR_WIN), get_seq_len(CLR_WIN));
    sleep(1);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, get_seq_name(POS_CUR_TOP_LEFT), get_seq_len(POS_CUR_TOP_LEFT));
}

Review Request:
Style, maintainability, bad practices, et cetera.

Okay, the first thing I see is that there's no common prefix among all the symbols here. (My perception changes the moment I become the reviewer, and not the coder.)

Sequence of #include headers:
Recommend sequencing header includes from "General" to "Specific":

C library headers (immutable generic for any/all C programs), then
OS library headers (immutable target platform APIs), then
Application headers ("globally" shared info between project's translations units)

Notice that #include <stddef.h> and include <stdint.h could, then, be removed from the application's header file new.h (or possibly sequences.h??). It's the translation unit (new.c??) that takes care to include all preliminary headers before it uses #include "new.h".
Suggest adding an "abstraction" level by separating color from cursor motions from general display services by adding trivial service functions to new.c. Picture the next project to be a visual editor with keyword highlighting like most IDEs these days. Keeping in mind that WHITE is for character constants, and PINK for keywords, and ... will drive the coder mad! Instead of pooling ~40 tokens for color, cursor, display functions, each to be retrieved through only 2 portals, write separate functions with meaningful names. The first cab-off-the-rank is your version of cls() (or clear() in some environments). The function name says it all; no need to expose the ANSI Escape Code, or a "homebrew" token that refers to that code. Just a very specific function call that performs a very specific function. Ponder on this for a while... (Spreadsheets, for example, use an internal representation of each cell with all of its attributes. Cell B52 in how one cell is referenced and rendered in a formula. Internally, the cell may be "known" as QZH374_FF. That separation/translation between the internal model and what the user sees provides tremendous flexibility!) Play with, for instance, set_text(); and set_alert(); as functions that know and always output the right ANSI string for "white on black" text and "red_on_white" text.
Notice that all those enum tokens are (or should be) only available to the source file where they are used. They do not have to be publicly accessible, and therefore the entire enum should be static inside the source file with the two get_foobar() functions. That leaves only the two function prototypes in that header file (as it should be). (Is it new.h or sequences.h?) (For future reference: include each file's name as the first line of the code. Eg: // my_file1.c. Do this for yourself as well as for us here on SO. Writing, "And, now the xxx file" makes it difficult to reference which piece of the code one is referring to.)
(Trivial: #define SEQUENCES_H is sufficient. The spurious 1 on that line is unnecessary.)
Application header files rarely need to #include other header files. The C Standard Library headers skirt this recommendation, but those have been written by experts for the convenience of not-so-experts.
Complex projects may be assembled hierarchically from many pieces wherein any "layer" has access to subordinate APIs that, in turn, have access to their own subordinate APIs (low level "helper" functions.) With attention to structure, one can achieve a good degree of opacity, the Holy Grail of writing robust code the leans-toward encapsulation and simplifies writing/running unit testing code.
If well organised, "top level" source files may-not/do-not need to know how really low-level processing happens (ie. they should not need to include anything but their own subordinate layer's header files.)
"It's turtles all the way down..."

Untested: (kinda trivial remark...) Test harness clears terminal display (twice). Cursor should be automatically restored to row/col (1,1) without explicitly moving it there.

Consider swapping order of name fragments:
COLOR_GREEN_FORE to COLOR_FORE_GREEN
(prefix is "COLOR" then "FORE/BACK" then particular "ragged" color name).
Or even (to taste)...
FORE_COLOR_GREEN as would be spoken in normal speech.
Example:
FORE_COLOR_RED
FORE_COLOR_WHITE
FORE_COLOR_BLUE

My preference is to be able to recognise, and then neglect, prefixes that are (necessarily) repetitive when scanning/searching a list of related 'tokens'.

If you can tolerate mnemonic extreme abbreviations:
FG_COLOR_RED
FG_COLOR_WHITE
FG_COLOR_BLUE
// line intentionally left blank
BK_COLOR_RED
BK_COLOR_WHITE  // or BG_COLOR_WHITE, for example
BK_COLOR_BLUE



Following is sample code offered to OP for purpose of "seeing other ways of doing things." OP has accepted this offer. These code snippets come from my homebrew Sudoku solver making blinky-flashy display on VT100 compatible device (Windows Terminal). All are 'compacted' and somewhat abridged and may contain oopsies.
// display.h
enum {
    CLR_WhtOnBlk, // <= aligns with array of ANSI strings
    CLR_BlkOnBlk,
    CLR_BlkOnGrn,
    CLR_BlkOnYlw,
    CLR_BlkOnPnk,
    CLR_BlkOnGry,

    CLR_Normal = CLR_WhtOnBlk, // Given meaningful names
    CLR_Puzl = CLR_BlkOnGrn,
    CLR_Keep = CLR_BlkOnGrn,
    CLR_Elim = CLR_BlkOnYlw,
    CLR_Erase = CLR_BlkOnBlk,

    CLR_Pause    = CLR_BlkOnGry,
};
char *clrStr( int clr );
void dispCell( Cell *p, int v, int clr, int hld );
void dispExam( Cell *p, int v, int clr );
void cursor( int ONoff );
void dispDebugErase( int r );

// display.c
#include <stdio.h>, <string.h>, <stdarg.h> // you get the drift
#include "main.h", "solve.h", "helper.h", "display.h" // you get the drift

char *clrStr( const int clr ) {
    static char *cstr[] = {
        "\033[0;0m",    // wht on blk - CLR_WhtOnBlk
        "\033[40;30m",  // blk on blk - CLR_BlkOnBlk
        "\033[102;30m", // blk on grn - CLR_BlkOnGrn
        "\033[103;30m", // blk on ylw - CLR_BlkOnYlw
        "\033[105;30m", // blk on pnk - CLR_BlkOnPnk
        "\033[47;30m",  // blk on gry - CLR_BlkOnGry
        "\033[106;30m", // blk on blu
    };
    return cstr[ clr ];
}

static void printAt( int r, int c, int clr, char *str ) {
    printf( "\033[%d;%dH%s%s", r, c, clrStr( clr ), str );
}

void cursor( int ONoff ) {
    printf( "\033[?25%c", "lh"[ ONoff ] );
}

// last param 'hld' is a duration to pause before continuing. Time to think.
void dispCell( Cell *p, int v, int clr, int hld ) {
    int r = PuzlTL_r + p->row*2;
    int c = PuzlTL_c + p->col*4;

    char str[] = "   "; str[1] = v2ch( v ); // turn int 7 into " 7 "

    printAt( r, c, clr, str ); // output @row,col with a fg/bg colour, a string
    ...
}

void dispDebugErase( int r ) {
    printAt( r, 1, CLR_Normal, "\033[0J" );
}


"(new.c??)" ===> I was too lazy to type sequences.h at the time of writing this code. I'd ensure that each file's name is present as a comment at the beginning henceforth. Thank you for the comments about the naming, I was looking for someone to speak of them.

@Harith Hey there! Just added a long paragraph about "another level of separation" between the enum tokens and the calling function. Eg: my_cls(); doesn't require any token to be exposed. All the info necessary is in the function's name. home(); or cr(); are simple one word instructions. home means TopLeft without clearing display, and cr means move to column 1 on current row... Things like that... It's late... I'm outta here... Cheers! :-)

@Harith I'm off for a bit. Plz let me know if you'd like me to add a version of your objective to my answer for you to examine. Code Review is to review your code! Just a friendly offer to share with you another way to achieve your objective (for educational purposes.) Cheers! :-)

"Picture the next project to be a visual editor with keyword highlighting like most IDEs these days." ==> My project actually is a text editor. I am rewriting Antirez's kilo text editor in C23. For now, I changed the array of structures to simple static const char *'s as the other reviewer suggested. But again, there are now 45 enum values that I'd have to keep track of and I might now actually abstract them away behind some functions.

Your offer is graciously accepted and appreciated, I am always open to new ways.

#include <stddef.h> is present in the header for size_t which the function prototypes require, and #include <stdint.h> is present in the header for 'uint8_t, which the enum` requires.

@Harith Ah, but... When sequence of #includes in x.c and main.c is correct, then C Std Library headers will always be included before local application header, so those requirements WILL be met without the local app header needing to include them on its own. Think carefully. :-) I've appended some code for you to have a look at. Notice I list all the <> includes BEFORE the " " includes. This works! :-)

@Harith In my code, yes, I let main level functions see the enum. I didn't want to invest the 1/2 hour to write a suite of get() functions. Cheap and dirty, in this case, but this is for my private use; not a full blown business app with 4 other coders involved. API was in my own brain. :-)

@Fe2O3 Consider posting your code as a question on Code Review, so we can review that as well :)

@G.Sliepen “Will you walk into my parlour?” said the Spider to the Fly, “‘Tis the prettiest little parlour that ever you did spy; The way into my parlour is up a winding stair, And I have many curious things to shew when you are there.” “Oh no, no,” said the little Fly, “to ask me is in vain, For who goes up your winding stair can ne’er come down again.” --- Mary Howitt... What? You think I was born yesterday? :-) Cheers!!

@Harith Just thought of an analogy... In a "single file" app, there is usually no need for explicit function prototypes. Organising function definitions places main() at the end of the file. Happy-happy! Organising #include lines is much the same.  at the head, then the "Court" and Royals" (ie: the app headers ) in increasing levels of sophistication(?)... Each tier finds its required foundations are already in place. Like case when 2 functions mutually call each other, analogy is not perfect, but you get the drift... :-) Cheers!

@Harith Final (I hope, you hope) pestering: YES, yes, yes! Always write "header guards" into your .h files. Very good practice! Note, however, that the recommended "sequencing" of well-designed #includes (ie: their content) usually means the header guards aren't really necessary. (This gets to be more difficult to achieve when the project becomes more complex.) Keep on doing what you're doing as it doesn't require much effort and might just save your *ss one day! Mentioning this now only to augment recommendation to deliberately "sequence" those #includes... Cheers! :-)

@Fe2O3, your first recommendation seems to be the opposite of accepted good practice.  Most C and C++ coders agree that new.c should include new.h first, so that we know it's complete and usable by other code without having hidden dependencies.  The headers required to implement the functionality can (should) be included after that.

@TobySpeight If what you suggest ("most coders agree") is true, then seems to be my lot in life to go against the grain... Even moderately complex projects should be made up from multiple components that "fit together" in complex ways. If a "lower layer" needs <stdint.h> internally, its .c should include that header. If a "lower layer" needs <stdint.h> for its interface to a calling layer (exposed function prototypes), the calling layer will have to include <stdint.h> to use the "servant" layer functions. (This applies to tokens, too.)

@TobySpeight This seems a weak argument until one gets into the design of many application headers. Desperate and undisciplined coders wind up with headers that all include each other (often multiple times). Then, the solution is that an app that is made from 30-50 source files and only 1 "all-inclusive" header file... (Yes, I've seen just such a codebase.) I think I'll stick with my proposal, even though I'm out of the game now...

@TobySpeight (imho) RAD principles that it's "desirable to facilitate copy/paste of blocks of code without slowing down to assess and trim to fit" are at the root of several global panics regarding hackers finding weaknesses... "Reuse by Easy Transplanting" without regard is NOT what I've found to be a winning strategy...

@Fe2O3, my experience with requiring callers to include the dependencies first is that the "desperate and undisciplined coders" end up including the whole standard library, just in case - or get caught out when the header adds a new function (whether or not the calling code ever uses it).  The iwyu tool exists precisely to reduce header inclusions down to the actual dependencies.  Including a header from many places should not be problematic, given the use of include guards - and I'm looking forward to being able to use module imports instead.  :)

Also, it's the approach that the Standard Library takes - imagine if you were made to include <memory> (to declare std::allocator) whenever you wanted to use <vector>?  Even though you are defaulting the allocator parameter?  And should that code all get broken when <concepts> got added?

@TobySpeight I learned C long, long ago when the ink on the pages of the K&R Bible Ver 1.0 was still wet; back when coding was a 'craft' and there were no 'tools' to keep the coder's fingers away from the spinning table saw blade. It may be codger-ly of me, but "all the mod-cons" seem to empower any dishwasher or taxi-driver (Valued member of the community notwithstanding!!) to consider themselves to be "coders"... Let's not talk C++ when the OP tagged C, please... (I realise that my opinion isn't worth the paper it's written on.) Cheers! :-)

@TobySpeight I acknowledge that the wizards in the back room that developed the Standard Library know a LOT more about this than I do. If they use #include in their header files, I trust that they know what they are doing. Us boys in the front office aren't usually as 'gifted'. This is the foundation for my earlier recommendation about "sequencing" and avoiding doing what the wizards are capable of... That's it in a nutshell.. Cheers! :-)

@TobySpeight Just Googled "How I became a software engineer"... Items like: "No degree. Not even coding bootcamp!!" I'm glad I passed through when the title carried some meaning... Cheers! :-) ... Revision: "How I became a software engineer without a computer..." LMFAO!!! :-)

This is not an abstraction
The title of your post is "Abstracting away ANSI escape sequences", but what you did is merely giving names to them. A real abstraction would be something like a curses library, which also allows you to move the cursor and change the text color, without hardcoding a one-to-one mapping to ANSI escape sequences.
Naming things
Avoid unnecessary abbreviations. Why not write escape_sequence instead of esc_seq? It really is not that much more to type overall, especially not with code editors having tab completion.
Don't call the sequence itself a "name".
Rely on compiler optimizations
In your code, esc_seq[] not only stores the string holding the sequence, but you also explicitly store the length of that sequence. However, you can call strlen() any time on a stirng to get its length, so you don't need to store the length yourself. And if you are worrying about performance, then the compiler has you covered: it can perform strlen() at compile time in many cases, if you enable optimizations and link-time optimization. If you are willing to rely on the compiler to do that for you, then you can simplify your code.
This also brings me to:
Consider storing the escape sequences as static const char*s
Instead of having an enum and an array with information about each sequence, you could just store them like so in a header file:
static const char* CLR_WIN = "\x1b[2J";
static const char* CLR_WIN_UPTO_CUR = "\x1b[1J";
static const char* CLR_WIN_UPTO_END = "\x1b[0J";
…

This avoids having to maintain both the enum declaration and the array definition, and allows even better compile time checking.

re: "Consider storing the escape sequences as static const char*s", since we're talking about C23, constexpr static const char[]s would also be worth considering.

@Brian61354270 and add [[maybe_unused]] to each chararacter array so that the compiler doesn't complain when it sees that only 5 out of 45 of them are used.

@Harith OR... either remove unused code or surround it with #if 0/#endif or /* and */. There is no reason to, and every reason not-to, have vestigial active code or variable definitions in a source file. The reader (may be you next year) wastes time scrutinizing active code that isn't even used?? This makes no sense... A good linker will discard what the compiler has spent time parsing and translating. If humans had been born without an appendix, many surgeries and/or tragedies would have been avoided.
